# Remove the Column names in to_excel in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to search the specific words are present in the dataframe. If word is present in the dataframe, need to export the subset of dataframe  in to Excel.
Here problem is every time it is calling columns names. Column names are same for all dataframes.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Ann', 'Juh', 'Jeo', 'Sam'],
    'Age': [43,29,42,59],
    'Task1': ['Drafting a letter', 'Sending', 'Pasting', 'Sending'],
    'Task2': ['Sending', 'Paking', 'Sending', 'Pasting'],
    'Task3': ['Packing', 'Letter Drafting', 'Paking', 'Letter Drafting']
    })

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:..\\pp.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
row = 0
b = ['Sending','paking']
    for var in b: ----> # Here 'b' is searchable keywords.


        lower_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())

        margin = df[lower_df.iloc[:,3:5].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(var.lower())).any(axis=1)]


        margin['search_term'] = var   ---> #Create the column with search keyword 


        if len(margin) > 0: --->    #If no data found need to eliminate
            margin.to_excel(writer,startrow=row)
            row = row + len(margin.index) +1


    writer.save()
```

If i use `header=False` it removes the all the column names but I want keep the starting of dataframe.

Comment: Is possible create some sample data, if possible excel file with 3-5 rows? Because now is not possible run your solution.

Comment: I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change logic - append each DataFrame to list `dfs` and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for final `DataFrame`:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pp.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

b = ['Sending','paking']
dfs = []
for var in b: # Here 'b' is searchable keywords.

    lower_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
    mask = (lower_df.iloc[:,3:5]
                    .astype(str)
                    .apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(var.lower()))
                    .any(axis=1))
    margin = df[mask].copy()

    margin['search_term'] = var   #Create the column with search keyword 
    #print (margin)

    dfs.append(margin)

pd.concat(dfs).to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: how to export into excel non present searching keywords data?

Comment: @dondapati - How working same solution, only changed `margin = df[~mask].copy()` ?

Comment: @dondapati - so is necessary remove duplicates? By all columns? `margin = df[~mask].copy().drop_duplicates()` ?

Comment: Just tested with sample data and working nice, so it seems data related problem.